# Is there a list of safe low-bandwidth software wallets?

Tags: light-clients, bandwith

Suppose a user has very limited access to the Internet and needs a safe low-bandwidth wallet while awaiting a hardware wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Use MyEtherWallet chrome extension, it is safe if you use a clean computer and it does not waste any bandwidth at all. The only traffic it generates is to check the balance and send already (locally) signed transaction.